# Gnuplot : My scripts seems to be good but I've the error " Invalid character \ "

Tags: plot, gnuplot, aix

I want to create a Gnuplot script with AIX 7.2 and Gnuplot 4.6

My script is :

```
set terminal png truecolor size 1950, 650  background rgb "#eff1f0"
set output "/home/tbenedet/GNUPLOT/used.png"
set datafile separator ';'

set size ratio 0.2
set bmargin at screen 0.2
unset key
set datafile separator ";"
set ylabel " MB BLOCK " font ",10" offset -1,0
set xlabel font ",10"
set xtics rotate by 45  offset -0.8,-9,-1.8


plot "/var/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/foo.txt" using 3:xtic(1) title column(2) with linespoints linewidth 2 pointtype 7 pointsize 1.5, \
     "/var/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/foo.txt" using 3:xtic(1) title column(2) with linespoints linewidth 2 pointtype 7 pointsize 1.5, \
     "/var/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/foo.txt" using 3:xtic(1) title column(2) with linespoints linewidth 2 pointtype 7 pointsize 1.5, \
     "/var/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/foo.txt" using 3:xtic(1) title column(2) with linespoints linewidth 2 pointtype 7 pointsize 1.5, \
     "/var/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/foo.txt" using 3:xtic(1) title column(2) with linespoints linewidth 2 pointtype 7 pointsize 1.5, \
     "/var/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/foo.txt" using 3:xtic(1) title column(2) with linespoints linewidth 2 pointtype 7 pointsize 1.5, \
     "/var/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/foo.txt" using 3:xtic(1) title column(2) with linespoints linewidth 2 pointtype 7 pointsize 1.5, \
     "/var/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/foo.txt" using 3:xtic(1) title column(2) with linespoints linewidth 2 pointtype 7 pointsize 1.5, \
     "/var/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/foo.txt" using 3:xtic(1) title column(2) with linespoints linewidth 2 pointtype 7 pointsize 1.5, \
     "/var/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/foo.txt" using 3:xtic(1) title column(2) with linespoints linewidth 2 pointtype 7 pointsize 1.5, \
     "/var/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/foo.txt" using 3:xtic(1) title column(2) with linespoints linewidth 2 pointtype 7 pointsize 1.5, \
     "/var/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/foo.txt" using 3:xtic(1) title column(2) with linespoints linewidth 2 pointtype 7 pointsize 1.5, \
     "/var/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/foo.txt" using 3:xtic(1) title column(2) with linespoints linewidth 2 pointtype 7 pointsize 1.5, \
     "/var/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/foo.txt" using 3:xtic(1) title column(2) with linespoints linewidth 2 pointtype 7 pointsize 1.5, \
     "/var/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/foo.txt" using 3:xtic(1) title column(2) with linespoints linewidth 2 pointtype 7 pointsize 1.5, \
     "/var/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/foo.txt" using 3:xtic(1) title column(2) with linespoints linewidth 2 pointtype 7 pointsize 1.5, \
     "/var/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/foo.txt" using 3:xtic(1) title column(2) with linespoints linewidth 2 pointtype 7 pointsize 1.5, \
     "/var/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/foo.txt" using 3:xtic(1) title column(2) with linespoints linewidth 2 pointtype 7 pointsize 1.5, \
     "/var/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/foo.txt" using 3:xtic(1) title column(2) with linespoints linewidth 2 pointtype 7 pointsize 1.5, \
     "/var/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/foo.txt" using 3:xtic(1) title column(2) with linespoints linewidth 2 pointtype 7 pointsize 1.5, \
     "/var/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/foo.txt" using 3:xtic(1) title column(2) with linespoints linewidth 2 pointtype 7 pointsize 1.5, \
     "/var/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/foo.txt" using 3:xtic(1) title column(2) with linespoints linewidth 2 pointtype 7 pointsize 1.5, \
     "/var/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/foo.txt" using 3:xtic(1) title column(2) with linespoints linewidth 2 pointtype 7 pointsize 1.5, \
     "/var/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/foo.txt" using 3:xtic(1) title column(2) with linespoints linewidth 2 pointtype 7 pointsize 1.5, \
     "/var/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/foo.txt" using 3:xtic(1) title column(2) with linespoints linewidth 2 pointtype 7 pointsize 1.5, \
     "/var/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/foo.txt" using 3:xtic(1) title column(2) with linespoints linewidth 2 pointtype 7 pointsize 1.5
```

At first sight, my script is correct... But when I try to run it with `gnuplot myscript.txt`, I've this error :

```
plot "/var/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/foo.txt" using 3:xtic(1) title column(2) with linespoints linewidth 2 pointtype 7 pointsize 1.5, \ using 3:xtic(1) title column(2) with linespoints linewidth 2 pointtype 7 pointsize 1.5, \ 
                                                                                                                                                                           ^
"myscript.txt", line 14: invalid character \
```

I don't know were are my errors... Could you show me ?

Thanks

Comment: Probably you reach the maximum length of the line. Try with only one row, then add one more, etc....

Comment: Or there might be something else after the \backslash; e.g. a CR-character (0x0d)

Answer (score 1):

Your plot command has a length of about 3600 characters. I'm not sure if there is a length limit or at least it must be more than 10'000, because I tried similar command with more than 10'000 characters and I don't get your error. 
By the way, in case you didn't know, you can shorten quite a few keywords: `using` to `u`, `title` to `ti`, `with` to `w`, `linespoints` to `lp`, `linewidth` to `lw`, `pointtype` to `pt`, and `pointsize` to `ps`

I guess (as Lorinczy Zsigmond already mentioned) you have some "invisible" character after `\`, it could also be `empty space` or `TAB`.
Some reasonable text editors can make "invisible" characters "visible". Check if there is any character after `\` in the same line.

From the gnuplot manual. Check `help introduction`:

> Commands may extend over several input lines by ending each line but the last with a backslash (). The backslash must be the *last* character on each line. The effect is as if the backslash and newline were not there. That is, no white space is implied, nor is a comment terminated. Therefore, commenting out a continued line comments out the entire command (see comments). But note that if an error occurs somewhere on a multi-line command, the parser may not be able to locate precisely where the error is and in that case will not necessarily point to the correct line.